# Connect QObject interface signal to a lambda Slot

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, lambda

I'm  trying to connect a QObject signal to a lambda slot but using an interface pointer to the object instead of a pointer to the concrete QObject class. But I get this wierd error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘FileSystemModel::connect(model_filesystem::Directory*&, const char*, FileSystemModel::setDirectory(model_filesystem::Directory*)::<lambda()>)’
 });
```

Here are some snippets of my code:

```
// Interface declaration
namespace model_filesystem {

class Directory {
public:

    virtual ~Directory()
    virtual QString name() = 0;

Q_SIGNALS:
        void changed();
        void failure(QString msg);
    };
}

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(model_filesystem::Directory, "org.moonlightde.panel.model_filesystem.Directory/1.0")

//Implementation
class GVFSDirectory : public QObject,  public model_filesystem::Directory {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(model_filesystem::Directory)
public:
    GVFSDirectory(const QString &uri);
    GVFSDirectory(GFile * gfile);

    virtual ~GVFSDirectory();

    virtual QString name();
public Q_SLOTS:
    void update();

Q_SIGNALS:
    void changed();
    void failure(QString msg);

// Usage
Directory * directory = new GVFSDirectory("/");
connect(directory, SIGNAL(model_filesystem::Directory::changed()), [this] () {
    setupModel();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> error: no matching function for call to ‘FileSystemModel::connect(model_filesystem::Directory ...

The `Directory` class is not a `QObject`. It **needs to subclass `QObject`** if it's going to use *signals* and/or *slots*.

From [Qt5 - Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html):

> All classes that inherit from QObject or one of its subclasses (e.g., QWidget) can contain signals and slots.

From [Qt5 - Plug & Paint Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-plugandpaint-example.html):

> To make it possible to query at run-time whether a plugin implements a given interface, we must use the Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE() macro.

This seems to provide the machanism to *query at run-time whether a plugin implements a given interface* so I don't see why there should be any expectation the `Directory` class should work like a `QObject` without subclassing it.

In other words, it's fine to use this without subclassing `QObject` but this doesn't grant `Directory` the ability to use *signals* and/or *slots*.

> SIGNAL(model_filesystem::Directory::update())

Even if `Directory` was a `QObject` there is no `update` signal, only `changed` and `failure`.

Comment: If you look at the end of the Directory declaration I called Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE. And you are right about the "update" signal, but the problem is not produced by it.

Comment: @AlexisLópezZubieta Maybe I'm missing something. Why do you think `Directory` can have signals without being a `QObject`?

Comment: According to the QT doc http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtplugin.html there is no need for the interface declaration to subclass QObject.

Comment: But you do **need to derive `QObject`** if you expect to use _signals/slots_ but `Directory` **doesn't derive `Qobject`** therefore you cannot _signals/slots_ with it.